# iOS: UIImage EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, memory-management

I am building a small iPhone only application (iOS SDK 6.0) and I am getting **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** exception in XCode.

The application has `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell`. I have implemented the `UITableViewCell` in a subclass (I call it `MyCustomCell` here) and added another parameter to the constructor:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier cellImage:(UIImage *)image;
```

The `UIImage` is added to `contentView` of the `TableCell` in the method, with following code:

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
imageView.image = image;

[self.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

This function is called within the function `cellForRowAtIndexPath` of course:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MyCustomCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier cellImage:self.cellImage] autorelease];
}

return cell;
```

The `cellImage` property of the `ViewController` (also the `UITableViewDelegate`) is declared as (it is also synthesized):

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage* cellImage;
```

The image is initialized in `viewWillAppear` method of ViewController with the following line:

```
cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image_resource.png"];
```

**This code works correctly, but the EXC_BAD_ACCESS appears, when I customize the image with iOS  6.0 only function**:

```
cellImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image_resource.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
```

Debugging helped me to locate the line that triggers the error - it is in the `initWithStyle` method of MyCustomCell implementation:

```
imageView.image = image;
```

I have looked through many `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors, I also read the tutorial of why does this error appear, but up to this point, I am not deallocating anything. Some object is probably released at this point, but I cannot find which one exactly and how could I fix the problem.

*I have also tried creating two properties in ViewController class, one to hold the original image and the other image with insets. It does not solve the problem, however.*

**Why is this an error? Why it is not working with image with insets? How could I fix this problem?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a property for cellImage, but you're setting it using the instance variable instead of the setter which has been created for you.  Since you're passing in an autoreleased object, there is a possibility that it's been released when you try to reference it next time.  Try using this below:

```
[self setCellImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image_resource.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch]];
```

Or with this:

```
self.cellImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image_resource.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
```

With this code, the image will be retained for you inside of the setter, and next time you try to use it, the memory will still be allocated and you shouldn't have any issues.

Consider also using ARC, if possible, as much of this intricate memory management stuff is handled for you.  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: As goes for the logic, you are correct. I am still getting used to the dynamic typing of Objective-C. The instance variable is apparently released sometime after. However, it still does not explain, why this did not happen, if the image was not set with insets. About ARC, I am aware of it, but this is a learning project and I want to learn memory management in detail, thank you though.

Answer (score 2):

The error appears when you execute the statement `imageView.image = image;`. Thus, the object `image` does not exist when this statement is executed. It must have been released before, either explicitly by a `[release image]` (since you don't use ARC), or implicitly if `image` is autoreleased (e.g. if you created it with `[UIImage imageNamed:...]`).
I think the best were to convert your code ARC, as Aaron Wojnowski suggested. Otherwise, check if `image` can be released unexpectedly.

Comment: Image is not defined as autorelease anywhere, so I assume the default is retain? I do not release the image explicitly anywhere.

Comment: But it can be defined as autorelease implicitly, e.g. with [UIImage imageNamed:...] as I mentioned in my answer. So, how did you declare image? With [UIImage alloc], which would retain it, or e.g. with [UIImage imageNamed:...], which would put it into the current autorelease pool?

Comment: You can see in the question, that it is declared with imageNamed, I am just not sure where could I get this information? I cant seem to find it on Apple dev site: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html d

Comment: You are right, "image" is declared with "imageNamed:" in your code. It is an autorelease object according to the Cocoa memory management rules, as pointed out in <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378206/do-all-class-methods-return-an-autoreleased-object>.